# SharePoint 2013 Project Templates Missing On Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2015

How can I enable the SharePoint 2013 Project Templates on Visual Studio 2015 -> New Project?

I have tried following this [URL](http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2013/03/18/articlehow-to-enable-sharepoint-2013-development-project-templates-in-visual-studio-2012/) but the installer doesn't work for 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I think Project Templates should be installed with Visual Studio and could be added after installation. You can try to start Visual Studio Installation and select "Modify" option, then select "Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools".

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools is only available in licensed version of Visual Studio (Professional/Premium/Ultimate).

You have to install the "Office Developer Tools Project". After you restart VS 2015 you will see a lot of templates show up under

'Installed --> Office/SharePoint'

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install Microsoft Office Developer Tools with update for Visual Studio 2015 as mentioned at [Office / SharePoint template missing in Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2012. It wasn't showing project templates for SharePoint 2013. Download the Office Developer tools from below link and install.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F6A4FFA-D409-40C8-AF68-F6F0CBE0A00D/ENU/officetools_bundle.exe

Complete reference below.

http://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2021/03/SharePoint%202013%20project%20templates%20missing%20in%20Visual%20Studio%202012.html